# Remove class from list-item on-click anchor link with removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, onclick

I'm having trouble with removing a class on-click on the Tab 2 list-item. These are links with underlines that show content.

The code so far fairly close, just need a little hand on seeing what I've missed.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mk-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>  
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab is-active"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mk-tabs-panes">
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane">Tab Content 1</div>
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane is-active">Tab Content 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.mk-tabs ul li a').click( function(){
            if ( $('.mk-tabs ul li').hasClass('is-active') ) {
                $('.mk-tabs ul li').removeClass('is-active');
            } 
            else {
                $('.mk-tabs ul li').removeClass('is-active'); 
            }
        });       
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, using `addClass('is-active')` in your `else` statement should do the trick .. additionally i think jQuery also has `toggleClass()` method .. also remember you may have to reset all elements first, except the current clicked one, before toggling the class on the current clicked element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two varying behaviors ...

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.mk-tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var container = $(this).closest('.mk-tabs');
    var currentTab = $(this).closest('.mk-tabs-tab');
    var currentIndex = currentTab.index();
    $(".mk-tabs-tab", container).not(currentTab).removeClass('is-active');
    currentTab.toggleClass('is-active');
    var panes = $('.mk-tabs-pane', container);
    panes.hide();
    if (currentTab.hasClass('is-active')) {
      panes.eq(currentIndex).show();
    }
    
  });
});
jQuery(function($){
  $('.mk-tabs2').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var container = $(this).closest('.mk-tabs2');
    var currentTab = $(this).closest('.mk-tabs-tab');
    var currentIndex = currentTab.index();
    currentTab.toggleClass('is-active');
    $('.mk-tabs-pane', container).eq(currentIndex).show();
    var panes = $('.mk-tabs-pane', container);
    if (currentTab.hasClass('is-active')) {
      panes.eq(currentIndex).show();
    } else {
      panes.eq(currentIndex).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
.mk-tabs-tab {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.mk-tabs-tab.is-active{
  background-color: red
}
.mk-tabs-pane {
  display: none;
}
.mk-tabs-pane.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mk-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>  
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab is-active"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mk-tabs-panes">
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane">Tab Content 1</div>
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane is-active">Tab Content 2</div>
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane">Tab Content 3</div>
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane">Tab Content 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mk-tabs2">
    <ul>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>  
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab is-active"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mk-tabs-panes">
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane">Tab Content 1</div>
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane is-active">Tab Content 2</div>
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane">Tab Content 3</div>
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane">Tab Content 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one thing I notice in the code, there's another div that displays content on the right side using `<div class="mk-tabs-pane is-active">` is-active appears and disappears on the click. So Ideally, looking to get that working as well. Having it disappear as well like the Tab links. Just reviewing your code.

Comment: well you obviously modified your question since i posted :-) ... hence its good knowing the full intent of the question/code and being able to see the all the code you've tried...

Comment: Fair enough, understandable. Just didn't realise the pane had a ``'is-active'`` class as well. Thought they were connected. I posted new code.

Comment: I have updated my code, but at this point i am kinda guessing as to what the final intended behavior is.

Comment: This works, but it's not working for my code. Just going to use the mobile version of the feature. I've maxed out my time on this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.mk-tabs ul li a').click( function(){
            if($($(this).parent()).hasClass("is-active")){
              $($(this).parent()).removeClass("is-active")
            }
            else
            {
              $(".mk-tabs-tab").each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("is-active")
              })
              if(!$($(this).parent()).hasClass("is-active"))
                $($(this).parent()).addClass("is-active")
            }
            
        }); 
    });
```

```css
.mk-tabs{
  display:flex
}
.is-active{
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mk-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>  
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab is-active"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: My code already does this, it's when Tab 2 is already selected and you click on again and the red background color would disappear. So none of the Tab links would be selected.

Comment: it's not happen in my code ... when you click again on red tab ... now what is the issue?

Comment: When the red tab is clicked (when already selected), it should be deselected. So all Tab links would appear as unselected.

Comment: i add a change all tab can hide.

Answer (score 0):

@farinspace I'm trying this. I think the bug is "closest" on the pane code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mk-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>  
        <li class="mk-tabs-tab is-active"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mk-tabs-panes">
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane">Tab Content 1</div>
        <div class="mk-tabs-pane is-active">Tab Content 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.mk-tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var currentTab = $(this).closest('.mk-tabs-tab');
    currentTab.toggleClass('is-active');
    
    //if (currentTab.hasClass('is-active')) console.log('on');
    //else console.log('off');
 
    if ( currentTab.hasClass('is-active') ) {
        $('.mk-tabs .mk-tabs-panes .mk-tabs-pane').toggleClass('is-active');
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @farinspace I am working on a modified version of the jQuery here. Update coming shortly.

Comment: @farinspace updated the jQuery with an if-statement.